# Load Camel's body dynamically depending on header

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I want to set to my body an SQL statement in order to be used by the jdbc component afterwards. I have my sql scripts in the resources, thus i can take advantage of simple language to load sth from resources with the usage of `resource:classpath`. The problem is that url is not static and I want to load different files depending on a header that I've got (``).

```
<!-- INSERT data -->
<setBody>
   <simple>resource:classpath:sql/${header.CamelCustomer}/Insert.sql</simple>
</setBody>
```

Assuming that I have 2 customers A, and B. That mean that I also have 2 directories

- resources/sql/A/Insert.sql
- resources/sql/b/Insert.sql

How it is possible to load the different files with the usage of the header?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the [content based router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want to avoid adding choice tags whenever a new customer comes.

Comment: In that case the [dynamic router](https://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html) should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Content Enricher integration pattern](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) and wrap your simple expression with [Language component](http://camel.apache.org/language.html) to get it evaluated.

This should return expected results:

**Java DSL:**

```
.enrich().simple("language:simple:resource:classpath:sql/${header.CamelCustomer}/Insert.sql")
```

**XML DSL:**

```
<enrich><simple>language:simple:resource:classpath:sql/${header.CamelCustomer}/Insert.sql</simple></enrich>
```

---

I have created sample unit test for demonstration.

**src/test/resources/sql/A/Insert.sql**

```
INSERT something INTO A;
```

**src/test/resources/sql/B/Insert.sql**

```
INSERT something INTO B;
```

**DynamicLoadResourceTest**

```
public class DynamicLoadResourceTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                        .enrich().simple("language:simple:resource:classpath:sql/${header.CamelCustomer}/Insert.sql")
                        .to("mock:done");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testContentEnrichResource() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint done = getMockEndpoint("mock:done");
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("CamelCustomer", "A");
        sendBody("direct:start", null, headers);

        headers.put("CamelCustomer", "B");
        sendBody("direct:start", null, headers);

        done.setExpectedCount(2);
        done.assertIsSatisfied();
        Assert.assertEquals(
                "INSERT something INTO A;",
                done.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody()
        );
        Assert.assertEquals(
                "INSERT something INTO B;",
                done.getExchanges().get(1).getIn().getBody()
        );
    }
}
```